# Selenium JavaScript Executor returns null for .checked but works for .click()?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm trying to determine if an element has been checked or not.

This code works, it clicks the element, but it doesn't return anything.

```
js.executeScript("return arguments[0].click();", element);
```

This code does not work:

```
js.executeScript("return arguments[0].checked;", element);
```

This code works:

```
js.executeScript("document.querySelectorAll('[name=abc]')[0].checked");
```

I need to be able to determine if an element is checked, by the element alone.

Yes, element.isSelected() is in selenium, but its not applicable for this requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I would expect that in case of java your second approach should actually work..

Comment: System.out.println(js.executeScript("return arguments[0].checked;", element)); this prints null

Comment: You're Right. 

I wasted 4 hours trying so many things. lol.

I have the wrong element path. It's on the input itself not the checkbox. smh.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct.

```
js.executeScript("return arguments[0].checked;", element);
```

I was using a wrong node as the initial element.